# How can we retrieve the cross-validation estimate error from local regressions in R?

Tags: r, loess

I've been retrieving the following cross-validation estimate errors for natural splines (as an example).

```
library(splines)

all.delta = rep(NA, 10)
for (i in 1:10) {
    fit = glm(mpg ~ ns(displacement, df = i), data = Auto)
    all.delta[i] = cv.glm(Auto, fit, K = 10)$delta[2]
}

fit.err = all.delta[which.min(all.delta)]
```

How would I retrieve the similar estimate error from the `loess()` function? I have been playing with the `loess.wrapper()` function from the `bisoreg` package but I can't figure how to retrieve the delta from that function.